# Rails Foo that has_many Bar and accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar not saving new_bar.foo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `Foo` and `Bar`.

Foo

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar
end
```

Bar

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I can create a `Foo` that creates a `Bar` with the proper parameters using `Foo.new(bar_attributes: ...)`, but I run into the problem that, when saving the new `Foo`, it says my `Bar` is invalid because its `foo_id` is blank. Shouldn't `ActiveRecord` be doing that for me automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set the inverse relation, as say at the [api at: Validating the presence of a parent model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar, inverse_of: :foo
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, inverse_of :bar
end
```

Comment: I thought that inverse_of was no longer needed?

Comment: With Rails 4.1, I think Rails attempts to automatically identify these inverse_of relationships. I'm not 100% on this, but I think it's only able to do that for words that it uses its Inflector on properly. In this case, since you set up a has_many :bar (as opposed to has_many :bars), it doesn't know how to set it.

Comment: @ccai : Yes, at rails documentation I found: "Note that if you do not specify the inverse_of option, then Active Record will try to automatically guess the inverse association based on heuristics.". I guess the answer, because I had the same issue few months ago.